# Filing 2D Array from the user

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, console-application

```
            Console.WriteLine("\n\t\t\tTwo Dimensional Array");
            Console.Write("\nEnter the number of rows in the array : ");
            int row = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("\nEnter the number of columns in the array : ");
            int column = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            string[,] array1;
            array1 = new string[row,column];

            for(int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("\nEnter the {0}th Row Element : ", i);
                array1[i, 0] = Console.ReadLine();

                for (int j = 0; j < array1.Length; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("\t& {0}th Column Element : ", j);
                    array1[0,j] = Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("\nArray Element at {0}th Row is : {1}", i, array1[i,0]);
                for (int j = 0; j < array1.Length; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("\t& the {0}th Column is : {1}",j,array1[0,j]);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
```

I wish to accept following from the user in the console:
1) Ranks (No. of Rows & Columns)
2) Data for the array

I have created the above, however, I get exception error consisting "Index is out of range"

What are the mistakes committed?

Comment: The `Length` property returns the total number of elements, i.e. R x C

Comment: @JohnWu, I have changed it to GetLength(i), in my case GetLength(0), it works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need the length of each [dimension in the array using GetLength()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.getlength?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Array_GetLength_System_Int32_).

Change:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
```

To:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array1.GetLength(0); i++)
```

and Change:

```
for(int j = 0; j < array1.Length; j++)
```

To:

```
for(int j = 0; j < array1.GetLength(1); j++)
```

Comment: When I used "Length(0)" it gave me an error, I had to change "Length" to "GetLength" and then it worked perfectly. Any idea why so? And yes, thank you very much.

Comment: I was simply tired and didn't type the correct function that I linked to.  I'll edit it.